# Ожечься или обжечься?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Как правильно говорить (писать) ожечься или обжечься? Судя по словарю Даля употребляются оба слова. Но в каких случаях какое из слов употреблять?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Считается, что глаголы с приставкой ОБ имеют более разговорный и более конкретный характер, чем глаголы с приставкой О.

В текстах используются оба глагола, но "обжечься" встречается чаще, особенно в прямом значении (получить ожог). Оба глагола могут иметь переносное значение - потерпеть неудачу.

Вообще говоря, в современном языке глагол "ожечь" чаще используется в значении "причинить боль каким-либо действием", например: ожечь (=хлестнуть) плетью коня, то есть таким образом проявляется обобщенно-книжный характер приставки О.

Примеры

1) То палец порежу, то кожу прищемлю, клеем ожегся. Захмелев, он облегчал себе душу горячим чаем, а она, Сима, оказавшись рядом, заботливо дула ему на блюдечко, чтобы он не ожегся.Ты столько раз ожегся, Бурнашов, и неуж не пошло в науку?

2) Его лицо было ярко-красным, как будто он обжегся на тропическом солнце.  От изумления я обжегся глотком чая. Если дважды обжегся на другой жизни ― значит, она не его.

Интересно:

Толковый словарь Ожегова

Ожечься, ожгусь, ожжешься, ожгутся; ожегся, ожглась; ожегшийся;ожегшись; сов. (прост.). То же, что обжечься. Ожегшись на молоке, дует на воду (посл.).

Толковый словарь русского языка Ушакова

ОЖЕЧЬСЯ, ожгусь,  прош. ожёгся, ожглась, сов. (к ожигаться). То же, что обжечься.

Получается, что у Ушакова - нейтральный стиль, у Ожегова - просторечие, а современный Яндекс исправляет "ожегся" как ошибку, пословицу тоже переделали.

Answer (score 2):

Толкователи не различают эти слова по смыслу. Из современной речи первый вариант практически исчез, но в языке некоторых литераторов ещё встречается, как и забытые производные слова ("ожигающий" несколько раз встречается у Ю. Бондарева). Сейчас это может иметь декоративный смысл (ради разнообразия; сторонником воскрешения забытых слов был, в частности, Солженицын) или проявлять консервативные речевые тенденции, сохранившиеся на малой родине автора. Показательно, что поисковые системы предлагают перевести поиск на "обжечься" ("обжигающий"). Можно было бы разнести эти слова по смыслу на "обжечься" (через прикосновение к горячему или жгучему) и "ожечься" (получить обширные ожоги), но второе слово всегда обходят через выражение "получить ожог". На мой взгляд, в будущих толковых словарях придётся слово "ожечься" ("ожигающий") помечать как "книжн."